# Filter observable array by object property

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, observable

I currently have an array of observables which I'm iterating over using an `*ngFor` loop with the async pipe.
I would like to filter the observables by a property value on the object, e.g

Original array:

```
[{ name: test1,
   type: type1},
 { name: test2,
   type: type2}
 { name: test3,
   type: type1}
 { name: test4,
   type: type2}]
```

I would like to filter this and make two new observable (arrays), one for type1 and one for type2

I tried `obs.filter(x => x.type == "type1)` but it returns nothing

I then tried `obs.mergeAll().filter(x => x.type == "type1")` and I can subscribe to this and log it to the console correctly but now it doesn't work with my `*ngFor` (async pipe). I'm guessing it's because the `mergeAll` means it's no longer an observable array? So do I need to convert it back?

Comment: What type is `obj.type`? string?

Comment: Yes it's a string

Comment: @AnjilDhamala Please don't edit posts to add random italic and bold markdown. The code markdown was ok (if incomplete), but the rest only made it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing pipe operator from RXJS6.

```
import { of, from } from "rxjs";

import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";

const obs = from([{
    name: 'test1',
    type: 'type1'
},
{
    name: 'test2',
    type: 'type2'
},
{
    name: 'test3',
    type: 'type1'
},
{
    name: 'test4',
    type: 'type2'
}]);

const source = obs.pipe(
    filter(data => data.type === 'type2')
)


console.log(source.subscribe(item => console.log(item)));
// prints {name: "test2", type: "type2"}
{name: "test4", type: "type2"}
```

If you want to get an array:

```
const items = [];
console.log(source.subscribe(item => items.push(item)));
console.log(items);
```